# DBI->connect using 'old-style' syntax is deprecated and will be an error in future versions

Tags: perl, dbi

I've found this error message. What makes it especially interesting, is that in ActivePerl-5.18 I don't get this. I've got this only with the perl-5.14 version in cygwin.

I get this message for the following command:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:$dbname","$login","$password");
```

What is the exact cause, and the current syntax? Why hasn't ActivePerl-5.18 with this command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be getting that error from the code that you've posted. That error is triggered when `DBI::connect()` is given four arguments and the fourth one isn't a reference. The "old-style" connect that the error refers to allowed you to pass the name of the database driver as the fourth argument. This is described in the last paragraph of the documentation for [`connect()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#connect).

You wouldn't be getting that error from your code as it only passes three arguments to `connect()`. Well, unless the parser is getting *really* confused :-/

Perhaps we need to see more of your code.

Comment: I'm getting this error with some really old code. The full error for me is "DBI->connect using 'old-style' syntax is deprecated and will be an error in future versions at C:/Perl/site/lib/Oraperl.pm line 96" It is Oraperl.pm line 96 which is calling the old-style connect in my case. They even admit it:     # we still use the old style connect call with an explicit driver
    my $dbh = DBI->connect($system_id, $name, $password, 'Oracle');